# La négation de l'infinitif

Tags: grammaire, négation, littérature, infinitif

On m'a dit que la négation de l'infinitif s'emploie ainsi:

> ne pas *inf*

dans le cas le plus simple. Cependant, j'ai lu la phrase suivant dans un livre récemment, qui m'a interpellé :

> Souvent, elle ressentait l’impression d’un terrible gâchis **de n’avoir pas** su profiter des moments où son père était encore là.

Alors que, j'aurais écrit :

> Souvent, elle ressentait l’impression d’un terrible gâchis de **ne pas avoir** su profiter des moments où son père était encore là

S'agit-il d'un choix stylistique, ou y a-t-il une règle qui couvre ce cas ?

Comment: « Petit » détail : *avoir su* est un infinitif **composé**.  Pas de problème pour l'infinitif simple « Je préfère ne pas parler » (si la négation doit porter sur *parler*, bien sûr). Mais face à l’infinitif composé soit on applique la règle de l'infinitif (négation complète avant ) ou des temps composés (la négation encadre auxiliaire).  Personnellement je ne vois aucun aspect stylistique dans l'un ou l'autre cas, mais peut-être qu'il y en a un...

Comment: Ah mais voilà - pas trop petit comme détail en fait. Effectivement, cela explique tout, merci ! D'ailleurs si vous mettez ce commentaire en dessous je l'accepterai en tant que réponse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***De n'avoir pas su*** est plus soutenu/littéraire que ***de ne pas avoir su*** (courant), qui lui-même l'est plus que ***de pas avoir su*** (relâché).

[image]

Comment: Je viens d'apprendre l'existence de Books Ngram Viewer grâce à cette réponse ! Merci, ça peut se montrer utile